# How many different (unordered) number combinations that can occur from rolling $n$ dice (with sides numbered from $1$ to $6$)

Tags: group-theory, permutations

This is a question from my grouptheory course. I want to do it with the burnside theorem. But i don't know wich group and set (i.e. which group acts on which set?) I should use. I was thinking of $G:=\mathcal{S}_n$ but then you have infinite groups...

Can anyone help me? thank you in advance!

Comment: See [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))  for a combinatorial solution.

Comment: yeah I know, but I want to do it with grouptheory :)

Comment: Why are you trying to shoehorn in a phrase like "group theory" here?  What do you think differentiates group theory from combinatorics?